# how to put object by an external URL to amazon s3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

With PHP

how to put object by an external URL to amazon s3?

So suppose I had a URL: http://example.com/file.avi I want to be able to move it into my bucket without downloading the file to my desktop and re-uploading the file. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please expand a little more your question. Do you want to do it programatically or manually, through a browser, for example? Also, is the S3 bucket under your control or is it third-party?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

S3 only supports copying objects from another S3 bucket, or uploading of local files.
It is not possible to upload a resource located at an external URL.
See here for more details:
[Put Object from remote resource in Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316616/put-object-from-remote-resource-in-amazon-s3)

Answer (score -4):

You can do it using S3.php by tpyo https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class

Even it is not included in his ReadMe file, you can use the putObjectString() static function of it but you must convert first the url to string file by doing

$fileUrl = file_get_contents("http://www.somesite.com/imagesample.png");

> S3::putObjectString($fileUrl, "yourBucket", "uploads/filenamehere.png");

More details: https://gist.github.com/neilmaledev/d255c42f1289a9ab9394121b7896d4d3